# CSV treatment and upload to Google Analytics

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

need some help with a Google Script that's responsible to fetch a CSV and upload to Google Analytics.

This is how I receive my CSV from my fetch:

```
sku|maxCPO
123-2-F|10
3212-123-G|10
145-1234-S|70.5
53455-245-A|52.5
12455-13-H|15.5
33352-45-E|10
2443-BOX-H|150
3455-BOX-N|200
```

What I have in my GoogleScript

```
function findCsvAttachment() {
      var csvDoc = UrlFetchApp.fetch("mycsv");
                                 
       var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvDoc, "|");
      return csvData;
}

 
    function processCsv(csvData) {
      var dataRows ="";
      var headers = 'ga:productSku,ga:metric3\n';
        for (var row = 4979; row < csvData.legth && csvData[row][0]!= ''; row++) {
          var currentDataRow= csvData[row][0] + ',' + csvData[row][1]+'\n';
          dataRows += String(currentDataRow);
    }
     
        var dataForUpload = headers + dataRows;
        return dataForUpload;
    }
 
    //assumes media dataType for upload https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData
 
    function uploadDataToAnalytics(data, accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId) {
 
        var dataBlob = Utilities.newBlob(data, "application/octet-stream");
 
        var upload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.uploadData(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, dataBlob);
 
        return upload;
 
    }
 
    ///////// ACTUAL IMPLEMENTATION OF SCRIPT /////////////
 
 
    var csv = findCsvAttachment();
 
    var csvForUpload = processCsv(csv);
 
   var analyticsUpload = uploadDataToAnalytics(csvForUpload, CONFIG.analyticsAccountId, CONFIG.analyticsPropertyId, CONFIG.customDataSourceId);
 
}
```

> I'm only getting the headers when I run the script, I don't get the rows... Any help is MUCH appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `csvData.legth` should be `csvData.length`

Comment: @cooper Thank you very much! I'm sorry I missed that, super awkward! thank you for your time and patience. Now I'm getting `Invalid cell data "maxCPO" at row 2 column 2. Expected data type: LONG.` I know it Is not related to the question, do you know how to fix it? Thank you very much

Comment: Solved!  Would you mind copy and paste your comment as an answer? This way I can accept and give you credit :)